# IoT Hub Deployment Manifest: Possible to specify module identity tags?

Tags: azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-edge, azure-iot-hub-device-management

When programatically deploying an Azure IoT Edge solution to IoT hub via a deployment manifest [(see here)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/module-composition?view=iotedge-2020-11#create-a-deployment-manifest), is it possible to also immediately specify properties (tags) for module twins? [like here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-module-twins#module-twins).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such functionality available in the manifest file.
Right now IoT Edge follow below syntax and moduleContent doesn't allow any other properties except properties.desired.

Anyways you can update after deployment from the module twin.

```
{
"modulesContent": {
    "$edgeAgent": { // required
        "properties.desired": {
            // desired properties of the IoT Edge agent
            // includes the image URIs of all deployed modules
            // includes container registry credentials
        }
    },
    "$edgeHub": { //required
        "properties.desired": {
            // desired properties of the IoT Edge hub
            // includes the routing information between modules, and to IoT Hub
        }
    },
    "module1": { // optional
        "properties.desired": {
            // desired properties of module1
        }
    },
    "module2": { // optional
        "properties.desired": {
            // desired properties of module2
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Yes! You can use Device Provisioning Service (DPS) for that.

> When you create an enrollment in DPS, you have the opportunity to declare an initial device twin state. In the device twin, you can set tags to group devices by any metric you need in your solution, like region, environment, location, or device type. These tags are used to create automatic deployments.

Reference: [Create and provision IoT Edge for Linux on Windows devices at scale using symmetric keys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/how-to-provision-devices-at-scale-linux-on-windows-symmetric?view=iotedge-2018-06&tabs=powershell%2Cindividual-enrollment)

Comment: At the point of sending the deployment manifest to the IoT hub, the device is already provisioned. I am not talking about setting a tag in the device twin, I want to set tags in the MODULE twin at the MANIFEST DEPLOYMENT stage.